# Make calculation n times

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I`m trying to make a loan amortization calculator in SQL Server with stored procedures.

I would like to generate rows that display the remaining payment for the current month

```
ALTER PROCEDURE loanCalculator 
    @loan float, 
    @month smallint,
    @interest float 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @monthly_pmt float;
    DECLARE @remain_payment float;

    SET @monthly_pmt = (@loan * @interest/1200)/( 1 - (1/(POWER((1 + @interest/1200), @month))))

    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @counter,
            CONCAT('$', CAST(@monthly_pmt AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS 'Monthly Payment', 
            CONCAT('$', CAST(@monthly_pmt * @month AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS 'Total payment',
            CONCAT('$', CAST((@loan - @monthly_pmt) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS 'Remaining payment'

        SET @counter = @counter +1
        SET @remain_payment = (@loan - @monthly_pmt)
    END
```

Comment: Would a while loop help? Here's some examples that may help if that's what you're trying to do https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-while-loop-with-simple-examples/

Comment: Storing monetary values as a `float` is an incredibly bad idea; it will often store approximate values, which for money means can and will not add up. For monetary values always use a pricise data data with a specific precision and scale.

Comment: I don;t understand: `@count` is not being declared. And this code will not loop (not that you want a loop anyway). I think you are best off working from a calendar table, combined with a running sum calculation